# Is it possible to access the tuple elements within the flow control of OPL?

Tags: cplex, opl

I am trying to solve a subproblem iteratively by calling it in the flow control. My subproblems contain sets of tuples. I am wondering if it is possible to access the tuple element inside the flow control (e.g. for updating data using for loop)?

Comment: What have you tried? Why not research this yourself by writing some code? See [ask]. This site works best when you can state a specific problem related to some code you share and tell us what wen wrong for you.

Comment: Thank You! I will consider that next time I post any question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided an example at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithoplchange/blob/master/changetupleset.mod

sub.mod

```
tuple t
{
 int e1;
 int e2;    
}
    
{t} y=...;

execute
{
  writeln("y=",y);
}

dvar float x;

maximize x;
subject to {
  x<=sum(i in y)i.e2;
}

execute
{
  writeln("x=",x);
}
```

and then the main block in main.mod

```
tuple t
{
int e1;
int e2;    
}

{t} s={<1,1>};

main {
  var source = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");
  var cplex = new IloCplex();
  var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
 
 
  for(var k=1;k<=5;k++)
  {
  var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
    
  var data2= new IloOplDataElements();
 
data2.y=thisOplModel.s;
Opl.item(thisOplModel.s,0).e2=Opl.item(thisOplModel.s,0).e2+1;
data2.y.add(k,k+1);

  opl.addDataSource(data2);
  opl.generate();

  if (cplex.solve()) {
     writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());
  } else {
     writeln("No solution");
  }
data2.end();
 opl.end();
 
 
}  
 
}
```